# Python - print values of a list embedded in a sentence without calling them individually?

Tags: python

Is there a way to print out the values of a list embedded in a sentence without calling them individually? For example, instead of doing this:

```
test = ["baseball","brother","sister"]
print ("Bob went out to play {} with his {} and {}.".format(test[0], test[1], test[2])).
```

Is there a way to shorten it to something like:

```
print ("Bob went out to play {} with his {} and {}.".format(test[0:2]))
```

Comment: You can star your argument list `"{} {} {}".format(*test[:3])`

Comment: Have a look at my new answer. By the way you shouldn't ask a question, someone answers it and then change your question and mark that person's answer down.

Comment: @Paul Panzer The star with or without the splicing does the trick! Thanks

Comment: But my way is so much easier...

Comment: @TheNumnut Thanks for your comment; I am trying to avoid calling each value individually.

Comment: @TheNumnut No, it isn't.

Comment: Ah, yes apparently `format` gracefully overlooks excess arguments.

Comment: @TheNumnut I'm sorry, I wasn't the one who voted your answer down.

Comment: No worries. It is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul Panzer points out in the question's comments, you can use `*` in front, though you'll need `*test[0:3]` instead of `*test[0:2]`:

```py
test = ["baseball","brother","sister"]
print ("Bob went out to play {} with his {} and {}.".format(*test[0:3]))
```

This produces:

```
Bob went out to play baseball with his brother and sister.
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why this seems to work with or without the [0:3]?

Comment: The `*` unpacks the values, without it you are just slicing the list so it is still just one item. You can also just do `*test` without the slice. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/4831822) should help explain the usage of `*`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation! Paul also mentioned above that format overlooks excess arguments.